# "HTTP error" randomly on image uploads

Tags: uploads

I have been getting "HTTP error." messages seemingly randomly when I upload images. The frustrating part is that if I get the error on an image, then try the same image again a few minutes later, it works. It's hard to debug when it's not consistent.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Pretty sure this is being caused by the Smush.it Plugin. Apparently their servers can't handle the traffic lately

Comment: If you have definitive solution please add it as an answer and accept so question doesn't haunt the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is being caused by the Smush.it Plugin. Apparently their servers can't handle the traffic lately.