# HTTP Error when trying to upload image

Tags: images, uploads

I'm getting an `HTTP error` when trying to upload an image. The image is 6MB, yet I was able to upload a 10MB image just previously. I set the following, but they did not help:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64MB');
define('WP_DEBUG', true); # could not start the upload
post_max_size = 12M # php.ini
upload_max_filesize = 12M # php.ini
max_input_time = 120 # php.ini
```

I restarted `httpd`. There is no message in `httpd/error_log`. I have Wordpress 4.0, and PHP 5.3.3.

None of the following answers were helpful.

[How to Fix HTTP Error When Uploading Images?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59763/how-to-fix-http-error-when-uploading-images)

["HTTP error" randomly on image uploads](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52085/http-error-randomly-on-image-uploads)

[HTTP Error when uploading images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51592/http-error-when-uploading-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated PHP to 5.3.3-38 (el6) and that seemed to fix it for now.

Comment: Please note that PHP 5.3 is obsolete version and no longer maintained. For your sake (and everyone happening upon this answer) try to run latest (currently 5.6) or at least stable version (currently at least 5.4). :)

Comment: @Rarst How is that possible? I run 'yum update' and it only goes to PHP 5.3?

Comment: sorry, not a server person so I got not idea why it gives you something that outdated.

Comment: @Chloe some linux distros are slow to bring packages up to the latest version in order to avoid any backwards compatibility issues. they usually apply any security fixes to the version maintained in their repos. you can update PHP by using another repo: http://www.servermom.org/upgrade-php-53-54-55-centos/1534/